# Finding records which doesn't exists in other oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find records which exists in table A but not in table B. If there is only one column to check, then I can use

```
select col_A,col_B,......from A where col_A not in (select Col_A from B).
```

But I have four columns which need to checked.

I did something like this, which works but is not the perfect way

```
select col_A,col_B,col_C,col_D from A where col_A||col_B||col_C||col_D not in (select col_A||col_B||col_C||col_D from B)
```

and also it takes lot of time to return results in case of large amount of data.

Please suggest the proper way of doing this.

Thanks.....

Comment: Which is the common column in table A and B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Oracle documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341

"MINUS Example The following statement combines results with the MINUS operator, which returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second:"

```
SELECT product_id FROM inventories
MINUS
SELECT product_id FROM order_items;
```

You requirements are a little bit more complicated. I assume, that the combination of cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d is unique for a record in table A. In that case, the following code should solve your problem:

```
create table A (
  cols_date DATE,
  cols_a NUMBER,
  cols_b NUMBER,
  cols_c NUMBER,
  cols_d NUMBER
);

create table B (
  cols_a NUMBER,
  cols_b NUMBER,
  cols_c NUMBER,
  cols_d NUMBER
);

insert into A (cols_date, cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d) values (sysdate, 1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into A (cols_date, cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d) values (sysdate, 2, 2, 2, 2);

insert into B (cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d) values (2, 2, 2, 2);
insert into B (cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d) values (3, 3, 3, 3);
commit;

select a.cols_date, a.cols_a, a.cols_b, a.cols_c, a.cols_d from (
  select cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d
  from A
  minus 
  select cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d
  from b
) ma, a
where 1=1
  and ma.cols_a = a.cols_a
  and ma.cols_b = a.cols_b
  and ma.cols_c = a.cols_c
  and ma.cols_d = a.cols_d;
```

Result is

```
COLS_DATE                 COLS_A     COLS_B     COLS_C     COLS_D
--------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.07.2013 13:20:02            1          1          1          1
```

NOT EXISTS will also solve the problem. This statement has a better execution plan then the MINUS version.

Thanks to David Aldridge for this solution.

```
select
  cols_date,
  cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d
from
  a
where
  not exists (
    select 1
    from   b
    where  1=1
  and b.cols_a = a.cols_a
  and b.cols_b = a.cols_b
  and b.cols_c = a.cols_c
  and b.cols_d = a.cols_d           
);
```

Comment: I also want to display columns which only exists in table A, so I believe minus will not work here.

Comment: Do you want to see something like this?

create table A (
  col_a NUMBER,
  col_b NUMBER
);

create table B (
  col_a NUMBER,
  col_c NUMBER
);

select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'A'
minus 
select column_name 
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'B'
;

Result: COL_B

Comment: @ Olaf H. Thanks for the reply, Not exactly.

Comment: Pleas explain your requirements or add an example to your original question.

Comment: @ Olaf H. Thanks for the reply, Not exactly. Lets say my A table have cols_date, cols_A, cols_B, cols_C and cols_D, and my B table have cols_A, cols_B, cols_C and cols_D. I want to display records from A table but also want cols_date column in output. So output columns are cols_date, cols_A, cols_B, cols_C and cols_D. cols_date column only exists in table A. The logic is similar to MINUS clause. But I believe Minus will not works here as cols_date only exists in table A. Thanks again for your time..

Comment: @ Olaf H. Spot on mate. This is what I was looking for...Thanks again.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be very efficient. I'd have a close look at the execution plan.

Comment: Yes explain plan contains 2 times a full table scan on A. If you have enough physical memory to hold A in the cache, then this shouldn't be a problem. I don't know a solution with a better execution plan. Using a temp table (WITH mine AS ..) leads to the same execution plan on my system!

Comment: I'd suggest the NOT EXISTS solution in my answer -- in the absence of more efficient full index scans it would likely be a single full table scan of each table, and no implicit sort-distinct.

Comment: I can't say that I'm happy about my answer being pretty much, though not exactly, pasted into your own. I know we're all supposed to be one big happy-to-help selfless family and all, but it doesn't seem right to me. Aside from my wounded ego, you now have two answers in one.

Comment: @ Olaf H. and David Aldridge -- Thanks both of you for your time and efforts that you put. Your solutions works perfect for me. Definitely "NOT EXISTS" works perfect from performance point of view. The only minor change is to do distinct count to get exact numbers in case of "NOT EXISTS" option.

Answer (score 3):

There's an implicit distinct on MINUS that you'd probably want to avoid.

A NOT EXISTS construct would probably be run as a hash anti-join, which would be very efficient.

```
select
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  ... etc
from
  table_a a
where
  not exists (
    select null
    from   table_b b
    where  a.col1 = b.col1 and
           a.col2 = b.col2 and
           a.col3 = b.col3 and
           a.col4 = b.col4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH mine AS (
  SELECT cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d FROM a
  MINUS
  SELECT cols_a, cols_b, cols_c, cols_d FROM b
)
SELECT a.cols_date, a.cols_a, a.cols_b, a.cols_c, a.cols_d
FROM a NATURAL JOIN mine
```